VueJS + Laravel 10: Проблема с сохранением файлов в дочернюю таблицу ответов в SPA-приложении
Я работаю над SPA-приложением на Vue.js и Laravel 10, где пользователи могут оставлять комментарии и ответы на них. Пользователь может прикрепить файл (изображение или текстовый файл) как к комментарию, так и к ответу. В таблицу комментариев загрузка файлов работает успешно, но я столкнулся с проблемой при загрузке файлов в дочернюю таблицу ответов — файл просто не сохраняется.
Вот метод create() в моем контроллере:
public function create(Request $request, $commentId)
{
$validated = $request->validate([
    'user_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'text' => 'required|string',
    'file_path' => 
    'nullable|file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,txt|max:2048',
]);

$reply = new Reply();
$reply->user_name = $validated['user_name'];
$reply->email = $validated['email'];
$reply->text = $validated['text'];
$reply->comment_id = $commentId;
$reply->parent_id = $request->input('parent_id');

// НЕ РАБОТАЕТ (файл не загружается)
if ($request->hasFile('file_path')) {        
    $file = $request->file('file_path');
    $path = $file->store('reply_files', 'public');
    $reply->file_path = $path;
}

$reply->save();

return response()->json($reply, 201);
}

Что происходит:

Файл не загружается в дочернюю таблицу replies.
Поле file_path остается пустым, хотя для комментариев загрузка 
файлов работает корректно.
Что я пробовал:

Проверял миграции и схемы таблиц, чтобы убедиться, что столбцы 
file_path существуют.
Пробовал различные способы сохранения файла через store и другие 
методы.
Удостоверился, что нет проблем с доступом к папке для сохранения 
файлов.
Вопрос: Что может быть причиной того, что файлы не сохраняются в 
дочернюю таблицу ответов, несмотря на успешную загрузку в 
таблицу комментариев? Может ли проблема быть связана с 
особенностями дочерней таблицы или с самим процессом обработки 
запроса?


Спросил у чат ChatGPT, не знаю, может поможет )
Проблема с загрузкой файлов в дочернюю таблицу ответов может быть вызвана несколькими факторами. Давайте рассмотрим возможные причины и решения:

Проверка формы:
Убедитесь, что форма, отправляющая данные для создания ответа, действительно включает поле для загрузки файла с именем file_path. Если имя поля отличается, Laravel не сможет его найти.

Атрибуты формы:
Убедитесь, что у вашей формы установлен атрибут enctype="multipart/form-data". Это необходимо для корректной отправки файлов:
 html
 <form action="/your-endpoint" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form- 
 data">
     <!-- другие поля -->
     <input type="file" name="file_path">
     <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
 </form>


Проверка JavaScript (если используется):
Если вы используете Vue.js для отправки данных через AJAX, убедитесь, что вы правильно формируете FormData и добавляете файл в него:
 javascript
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('user_name', this.userName);
 formData.append('email', this.email);
 formData.append('text', this.text);
 formData.append('file_path', this.selectedFile); // убедитесь, что это файл 


 axios.post(/your-endpoint/${commentId}, formData, {
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 }
 });


Логи и отладка:
Проверьте логи Laravel (storage/logs/laravel.log), чтобы увидеть, есть ли какие-либо ошибки, связанные с загрузкой файла.

Права доступа к директории:
Убедитесь, что директория storage/app/public/reply_files существует и имеет правильные права доступа. Вы можете установить права доступа с помощью команды:
 bash
 chmod -R 775 storage/app/public/reply_files


Проверка валидации:
Убедитесь, что файл действительно проходит валидацию. Вы можете временно добавить вывод ошибок валидации в ответе контроллера:
 php
 if ($validated) {
     return response()->json($validated);
 }


Тестирование загрузки файла отдельно:
Попробуйте временно упростить код и протестировать только загрузку файла без остальных полей, чтобы убедиться, что проблема именно в файле.


Если после всех этих проверок проблема все еще остается, попробуйте сделать вывод отладочной информации, чтобы понять, что именно происходит на этапе обработки запроса.
